# Android Fragment Visibility is not seen for first time

Tags: android, fragment

I need to make a fragment visible and invisible depending on the menu button click. I am using getView.getvisibility to check whether its visible or not. for the first time it returns 0 which as per my condition is considered to be visible and doesn't show the fragment.
My code:

```
LinearLayout menuButton = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.home_button);     
        if(menuButton != null)
        {           
            menuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {   
                    Fragment navFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_list_fragment);
// First time the value of navFragment.getView().getVisibility() is 0
                    if(navFragment.getView().getVisibility() == 8)
                    {
//if visibility value is 8, make the fragment visible
                        navFragment.getView().bringToFront();   
                        navFragment.getView().setVisibility(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
//if visibility value is 0, make the fragment invisible

                        navFragment.getView().setVisibility(8);
                    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you inflate the layout for your fragment, you should ensure that the visibility is set to GONE.  The default for a view (and thus your fragment) is VISIBLE.

Also, you should use the constants View.VISIBLE and View.GONE instead of 0, 8.

Answer (score 0):

in on create add the fragment to your view, and immediately hide it using hideFragment

```
   public void hideFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        Log.d(TAG, "hiding fragment");
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.hide(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    Log.d(TAG, "showing fragment");
    if (fragment.isAdded() && fragment.isHidden()) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.show(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

 Fragment navFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_list_fragment);//put this outside the click method


menuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   

                if(fragment.isAdded() && fragment.isHidden()){
                      showFragment(fragment);
                 }
                else
                {
                      hideFragment(fragment);
                }
});
```

Comment: I replaced with your code, it doesn;t launch the fragment at all

Comment: how do you add your fragment to the view ?